# Placing Un-Ordered Lists Next to Each Other

Tags: css

I've been working on an application that looks like [THIS](https://jsfiddle.net/06g9zL3v/4/) jsfiddle. As one can make out, there are unused whitespace between any two UL elements. I would like to remove this, so that, the space is used evenly. Here's the section of the CSS that styles the div/ul/li.

```css
.vertical-tree{
    display: flex;     
    flex-wrap: wrap;     
    line-height: 0.5em;
}

.vertical-tree ul{
    padding-left: 25px;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, auto);
    justify-content: space-between;
    gap: 0 1em;
}
.vertical-tree li {
    margin: 0px 0;
    list-style-type: none;
    position: relative;
    padding: 2px 5px 0px 1px; /*trbl*/
}
```

Space that I wish to get rid of:

[image]

Please help.

Comment: Can you screenshot and mark the space you want to remove?

Comment: Not a Task for CSS-Grid. Can be done with Flexbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution is to change the flex-direction to "column" and let the first `<ul>` take up the whole space of the first column: [fiddle with solution](https://jsfiddle.net/5vau41wd/) (assuming that the first `<ul>` is the largest one)

See explanation to changes as comments inside the CSS:

```
.vertical-tree {
    display: flex;     
    flex-wrap: wrap;     
    line-height: 0.5em;
/* set direction in which items are placed into the flex container to "column": */
    flex-direction: column; /* added */
/* set a height (could also be px), so that flex-basis can take effect: */
    height: 100vh; /* added */
/* removes gap between columns: */
    align-content: start; /* added */
}


/* target only first ul inside flex container: */
.vertical-tree ul:first-child {
/* let the first ul in the flex container take up the whole column
(needs a height on the flex container): */
  flex-basis: 100%; /* added */
}
```